# What is the operator precedence of "=" in Python?

Tags: python, operators, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

[Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) doesn't mention the operator precedence of `=`. So what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`=` is not an operator. `=` is an [assignment **statement**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Because it is a statement, it can't be part of an expression (expressions are instead part of certain statements, and never the other way around), so ordering is irrelevant. The expression is always executed to serve a statement.

For assignments, the grammar specifies that specific types of expressions are permitted after the `=` symbol:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)
```

and the documentation for that statement details what order things are executed in:

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.